# Golang function generalization for different packages

Tags: go, interface

Imagine these functions needs to be used how can I make this calls generic so that I don't repeat almost the same code.

with "encoding/csv"

```
func getDataFromCSVFiles(files []string) (error, Data) {
        data := Data{}
        for _, file := range files {
            f, err := os.Open(file)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
                return err, data
            }
            defer f.Close()
            r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f)
            reader := csv.NewReader(r)
            for i := 1;;i++ {
                rec, err := reader.Read()
                if i == 1 {
                    //Skipping header
                    continue
                }
                if err != nil {
                    if err == io.EOF {
                        break
                    }
                    //TODO log error line and csv filename
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                addWorkbook(rec, &data)
            }
        }
        return nil, data
    }
```

and with
    import fw "github.com/hduplooy/gofixedwidth" which is almost the same except calling fw.NewReader

```
func getDataFromPRNFiles(files []string) (error, Data) {
    data := Data{}
    for _, file := range files {
        f, err := os.Open(file)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
            return err, data
        }
        defer f.Close()
        r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f)
        reader := fw.NewReader(r)
        for i := 1;;i++ {
            rec, err := reader.Read()
            if i == 1 {
                //Skipping header
                continue
            }
            if err != nil {
                if err == io.EOF {
                    break
                }
                //TODO log error line and csv filename
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            addWorkbook(rec, &data)
        }
    }
    return nil, data
}
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, this tool (by me) helps with writing generic code in a similar way and it's not usage specific https://github.com/dc0d/goreuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only apparent difference is:

```
reader := csv.NewReader(r)
```

versus:

```
reader := fw.NewReader(r)
```

I'm not sure what `fw` is but presumably both readers implement a common interface:

```
type StringSliceReader interface {
    Read() ([]string, error)
}
```

So you could pass the openers (`csv.NewReader` and `fw.NewReader`) as function arguments:

```
func getDataFromFiles(files []string, func(r io.Reader) StringArrayReader) (error, Data) {
    //...
}
```

but you'd need to wrap them in little functions to get around the return types:

```
func newCSVReader(r io.Reader) StringSliceReader {
    return csv.NewReader(r)
}

func newFWReader(r io.Reader) StringSliceReader {
    return fw.NewReader(r)
}
```

Also, `defer` queues up things to execute when the *function* exits, not on the next iteration of a loop. So if you do this:

```
for _, file := range files {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return err, data
    }
    defer f.Close()
    //...
}
```

and `files` has a hundred entries then you'll have a hundred open files before any of them are closed. You probably want to move that loop body to a separate function so that you only have one file open at a time.

Furthermore, `error` is usually the last return value from a function so you should `return data, err` to be more idiomatic.

The result could look something like this:

```
type StringSliceReader interface {
    Read() ([]string, error)
}

type NewReader func(r io.Reader) StringSliceReader

func newCSVReader(r io.Reader) StringSliceReader {
    return csv.NewReader(r)
}

func newFWReader(r io.Reader) StringSliceReader {
    return fw.NewReader(r)
}

func getDataFrom(file string, data *Data, newReader NewReader) error {
    f, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()

    r := charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f)
    reader := newReader(r)
    for i := 1; ; i++ {
        rec, err := reader.Read()
        if i == 1 {
            continue
        }
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        addWorkbook(rec, data)
    }
    return nil
}

func getDataFromFiles(files []string, newReader NewReader) (Data, error) {
    data := Data{}
    for _, file := range files {
        err := getDataFrom(file, newReader, &data)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
            return data, err
        }
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

and you could say `getDataFromFiles(files, newCSVReader)` to read CSVs or `getDataFromFiles(files, newFWReader)` to read FW files. If you want to read from something else, you'd just need a `NewReader` function and something that implements the `StringSliceReader` interface.

You might want to bury/hide the `charmap.ISO8859_1.NewDecoder().Reader(f)` stuff inside the `NewReader` functions to make it easier to read non-Latin-1 encoded files. You could also replace `newReader NewReader` with a `map[string]NewReader` in `getDataFromFiles` and choose the `NewReader` to use based on the file's extension or other format identifier.

Comment: In Go, `[]string` is a slice type, not an array type. Therefore, `StringArrayReader` should be `StringSliceReader`. [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec): [Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types) and [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types).

Comment: @peterSO Right, thanks for the reminder, still pretty new to Go over here.